# Críticas de validação para campos de formulário

Tags: php

Estou tendo um problema em fazer as críticas de campo em branco de um formulário.
Eu fiz as críticas em um arquivo verifica.php sendo que sempre que eu preencho os campos e tento gravar as informações no banco de dados, aparecem todas as críticas, e todo o código que foi desenvolvido.
Até agora não consegui achar o erro de jeito nenhum, e já fiz inúmeras pesquisas e nada.

Alguém pode avaliar o códio e ver se acha o erro???  Obrigada!!!

O código completo está abaixo.

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Guia de Consulta CNS"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css" />
</head>
<?php

$tAut       =$_POST ["tAut"];
$tPrest     =$_POST ["tPrest"];
$tCart      =$_POST ["tCart"];
$cDadm      =$_POST ["cDadm"];
$tNome      =$_POST ["tNome"];
$tNasc      =$_POST ["tCnasc"];
$tCnpj      =$_POST ["tCnpj"];
$tNomecont  =$_POST ["tNomecont"];
$tCodcnes   =$_POST ["tCodcnes"];
$tProf      =$_POST ["tProf"];
$tEsp       =$_POST ["tEsp"];
$tConsr     =$_POST ["tConsr"];
$tNcons     =$_POST ["tNcons"];
$tCbos      =$_POST ["tCbos"];
$tDatatm    =$_POST ["tDatatm"];
$tTab       =$_POST ["tTab"];
$tCodp      =$_POST ["tCodp"];
$erro       =0;

//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tAut) OR strstr ($tAut, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento da Autorização obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}

//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tPrest) OR strstr ($tPrest, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento do Número da Guia do Prestador obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}

//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tCart) OR strstr ($tCart, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento do Número da Carteirinha obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}

//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($cDadm) OR strstr ($cDadm, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento da Data de Admissão obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tNome) OR strstr ($tNome, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento do Nome obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tNasc) OR strstr ($tNasc, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento da Data de Nascimento obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tCnpj) OR strstr ($tCnpj, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento do CNPJ obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tNomecont) OR strstr ($tNomecont, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento do Nome do Contratado obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tCodcnes) OR strstr ($tCodcnes, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento do Código CNES obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}

//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tProf) OR strstr ($tProf, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento  do Profissional Executante obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tEsp) OR strstr ($tEsp, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento da Especialidade obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tConsr) OR strstr ($tConsr, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento do Conselho Regional obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tNcons) OR strstr ($tNcons, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento do Número do Conselho obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tCbos) OR strstr ($tCbos, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento do Número do CBOS obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tDatatm) OR strstr ($tDatatm, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento da Data de Atendimento obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tTab) OR strstr ($tTab, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento da Tabela  obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tCodp) OR strstr ($tCodp, ' ')==FALSE)
{echo "Preenchimento do Código do Procedimento obrigatório!<br>"; $erro=1;}
//Verifica se não houve erro.

if ($erro==0)
{echo "Todos os campos preenchidos corretamente!";
    include "insere.inc";}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dicas: 1) Utilize nomes legíveis para as variáveis. 2) Utilize um `array` para armazenar e organizar as mensagens de erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua marcação HTML está errada, repare no seu código:

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Guia de Consulta CNS"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css" />
</head>
```

O correto seria:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="Guia de Consulta CNS"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
```

Obs: Quanto ao seu código PHP, tente guardar as mensagens de erro em um `array`

Tente apenas assim:

```
if (empty($tAut))
{
   $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Autorização obrigatório!<br>';
}
```

Para exibir os erros faça assim:

```
if (isset($error))
{
    foreach($error as $msg) {
       echo $msg;
    }
}
```

É só uma sugestão assim fará que mostre um aviso de cada vez. (Faça com todos os campos).

Só uma pergunta, cade seu formulário? poderia mostrar ?

Verifique se o botão do fomulário foi pressionado:

```
if(isset($_POST['nome_do_botão_do_formulário'])) {
   //código PHP
}
```

Comment: Fiz conforme disser e continua apresentando os erros.

Comment: qual erro que mostra ? Obs: Fiz uma edição no post na parte que mostra o `foreach`

Comment: Adicionei o foreach e diminuiu os erros que apareciam em tela. Mas mesmo estando preenchidos, aparecem.

Comment: vc tem que verificar se o post existe...

Comment: Deu super certo! Os erros que apareceram, são dois que eu preciso preencher, se não estiver preenchidos, apresentarão em tela. 
Obrigada!!!

Answer (score 0):

O  detalhe é que o seu código quando percebe um erro ele imediatamente escreve o erro na tela.

Uma implementação mais interessante é criar um array de erros. Dentro desse array você guarda a ultima ocorrencia de erro para cada um dos campos.

```
$erro = array( "tAut"=>"","tPrest"=>"");

if(!$tAut){
   $erro['tAut'] = "O valor é falso";
}

if(empty($tAut)){
   $erro['tAut'] = "Preenchimento em branco";
}

if($tPrest<11){
   $erro['tAut'] = "Valor inválido";
}
```

Depois basta você escrever o erro na página caso ele exista. Se houver mais de um erro para o mesmo campo, apenas o ultimo será exibido

```
if (isset($erro['tAut'])){
   echo $erro['tAut'];
}
if (isset($erro['tPrest'])){
   echo $erro['Prest'];
}
```